# Get a list of images in the project in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, image, list, uiimage

I imported a lot of images into my app. I could use `imageNamed:` for each item but it is very hard to do manually (~50 images). Can I somehow get a list of them? It is just for testing purposes, so private api is acceptable too.

Or will it be easier for me to rename them to something like 1.jpg, 2.jpg and etc.

Comment: Yes do it like 1,2,3........

Comment: okay, if so then suggest me a better way to rename them except of the manual one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way for you is rename you file to ( 1,2,3 xxx )

but there is a tool that help you to see you picture from app bundle during your coding

[KSImageNamed](https://github.com/ksuther/KSImageNamed-Xcode)

Comment: okay, if so then suggest me a better way to rename them except of the manual one. `KSimageNamed` is interest thing but it is not suitable for my situation too

Comment: you can use Automator  or check this link :
http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/3-easy-ways-to-batch-rename-files-on-the-mac--mac-46999

Comment: I found a better way - `Double commander` app but okay, accepted